# How can i get the start and the end indexes of a drift while using StreamGenerator Class of the stream-learn module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-stream, drift

I have generated some data with drift (abrupt, gradual, recurrent, and incremental). I want to compare some drift detectors algorithm on each but for that, I need the specific starting and ending position of where the drift occurs. Any idea?

For example, between 500 to 1000 and 2000 to 2500, I think the drifts occur but I'm not sure, and for what I want to do this needs to be precise. In red we can see concept probability, in blue the stream generated and other plots are drift detectors.
Link to stream learn [Documentation](https://stream-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [github](https://github.com/w4k2/stream-learn).

Looking at the concept_probabilities vectors try to identify how I can handle it but I wasn't... because sometimes it starts at 1, 0.99, 0.98 and fall into 0 but sometimes 0.01, and so on.
[Image of streaming data, concept probability, and drift detectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZ6f.png)